# Elmah max log entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah

I'm saving exceptions generated by [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) as XML files.

Is there any way to configure it so that it automatically removes files older than X days? Or perhaps a max number of files in the directory? Or do i need to created a custom batch job that does this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479461/elmah-log-files-deletion-manually-or-is-there-a-setting

Comment: @cocln Thanks, but I've seen that. "You can set the maximum number of log entries". Ok, but how? :)

Comment: That example @CocLn referenced (in the accepted answer) shows the use of the 'size' param in the web.config

Comment: According to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4479839/1185136) you can limit the log entries in memory. Maybe this works for XML files too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Elmah Project Site](http://code.google.com/p/elmah) for [ErrorLogImplementations](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorLogImplementations). (Italics added for emphasis)

> **XmlErrorLog**
>
> The XmlFileErrorLog stores errors into loose XML files in a configurable directory. Each error gets its own file containing all of its details. The files can easily be copied around, deleted, compressed or mailed to someone for further diagnostics. It does not require any database engine or setup, like with SQL Server and Oracle, so there is very little management overhead and you do not need to worry about additional costs when it comes to hosting plans. Although simple, it relies on the file system performance for shredding through the directory, reading files and sorting through them. *A smart way of keeping logs based on XmlFileErrorLog running smoothly is to limit the number of files by scheduling a task to periodically archive the old logs and clean up the folder.*

You will need to create a custom batch job that does this.

Comment: Thank you, got a bit confused, because there was a max number flag when using the "memory-storage", but couldnt find it on xml files.

Comment: Your link to the Elmah Project Site is broken.